# How can I get the sum of the outputs of an equation from a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know how I can get the sum of the numbers themselves in a range, but if I had an equation written in a for-loop such as the following:

```
for t in range(0,6):
    velocity = (.2*(t**2)) + 3
```

How could I get Python to add all the outputs of the equation together?

Comment: A one line solution: `sum(0.2 * (t ** 2) + 3 for t in range(6))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the value of `velocity` obtained in every iteration as below:

```
velocity = 0
for t in range(0,6):
    velocity += (.2*(t**2)) + 3
print (velocity)
```

Output:

```
29.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the result of the formula to a variable defined outside the for loop

```
sum_velocity = 0 

for t in range(0,6):
    sum_velocity += (.2*(t**2)) + 3
```